# How to handle checkbox using json object in angularjs 4

Tags: json, angular, modal-dialog

I had displayed below data in checkbox,

```
roomLists = {'4': {'name': 'Standard Room', 'typeID': '4', 'price': 100}, '5': {'name': 'Delux Room', 'typeID': '5', 'price': 100}}
```

this json object is retrieve using http. For testing purpose i have store it in roomlist.

Using pipe, data are getting display properly inside modal

```
 <app-modal #modal1>
   <div class="app-modal-body">
    <div *ngFor="let room of roomLists | jsonPipe">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox"/>{{room.name}}
     </label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

but when I try to click on check box its not getting click. Is something i m missing in code.

Comment: Angular 4? wow, they so quick

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are pairing `checkbox` with its own `label`, you can try give checkbox an `id` and and give `label` a `for` property which bind to the id of checkbox.

```
<div *ngFor="let room of roomLists | jsonPipe; let i = index;">
  <label for="{{'checkbox' + i}}">
    <input id="{{'checkbox' + i}}" type="checkbox"/>{{room.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried your solution its not working.

Comment: @SudhaBisht still cannot get checked?